# Typo3 11: How to enable layout field for plugins when editing the content element?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I've added some custom layout properties to the TCEForm to the appearance tab of a content element.
But it doesn't work for any type of plugin. The field is just missing.

[image]

Comment: Normally, `layout` is part of the `frames`-palette which ist also used by plugins (`$GLOBALS['TCA'][#tt_content']['types']['list']`). Maybe you (or you admin) has disabled this field via pageTS (`TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.types.list.disabled=1`)?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Thanks for the hint. I found the issue now. Some extensions were excluding the field via 
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist'][<plugin>] = 'layout'`

Comment: I summarized my idea and your specific reason into an answer, so the thread can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `layout`-field is part of the `frames`-palette which is also used by plugins (`$GLOBALS['TCA'][#tt_content']['types']['list']`).

- It is possible that someone (or an extension) has disabled this field
  via pageTS (`TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.types.list.disabled=1`).
- Excluding this field via
  `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist'][<plugin>] = 'layout'` is also possible